# Flutter Website is crashing on iOS 16.6 and later versions safari, chrome browsers

Tags: ios, flutter, web, flutter-web-browser, ios-web-app

I have a fully functional E-commerce flutter website, It works on PC, laptops and Android devices browser, but it's not working in iOS latest versions it keeps crashing.

I tried finding a solution and tried almost all methods, such as optimizing code, build as html renderer, canvas, etc. It shows high memory consumption, but I can't reduce it. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/memory

Comment: I am trying in website, this is for app @pskink

Comment: It is not working for the website, this is for the application. still, I am trying